# Serialization compatibility and changing a class

Tags: java, xml

I had been serializing objects to a file using an object output stream but ran into issues with not being able to change things in the class and then later read in that serialized object. In reaction to this, I decided I would use xml for storing my object data.

Would that same issue apply to xml? If I change some things up in  a class that I had written to an xml file and then load that file back in and cast it into an object, will I be able to do so? Thank you.

Comment: It depends. What do you plan changing? Are your changes consistent or it varies? Will you remove things, add things or modify thing?

Comment: Over time I would most likely edit methods, add methods/variables.

Comment: Check JAXB, I believe it will be fine as long as you don't go overboard.

Comment: The posts in this blog have helped me a lot on countless occasions http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/jaxb-xml-binding-standard.html . It might come handy if you decide to go with xml representation.